# AdminLTE & Laravel installation error with XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I am having troubles installing Laravel with the AdminLTE onto my local XAMPP server. I am trying to install this package:

- https://learninglaravel.net/adminlte-template-laravel-5-package
  here which requires me to install latest laravel

The install is done via composer with the following command:

- `composer global require "acacha/adminlte-laravel-installer=~2.0"`
  This seems to work fine.

The problem occurs when trying to create my new project via

- `laravel new laravel-with-admin-lte`

which returns a

- `laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Naturally I had a look at my Windows 10 Environment Variables and found that **Path** is correctly defined as: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`.
[image: pic1]

Inside the `\vendor\bin` directory I see this:
[image: pic2]

If I rename those two files to `laravel` only, and then run the `laravel new` command, I receive a `command "new" is not defined` error.

No clue anymore what to do, can someone help please?

Thanks,
A2k

Comment: Did all that and no result. Closed the cmd and restarted, no result. Changed the dynamic path with a static one (no %userprofile%) and also no result. Really no idea why...

Comment: What does your full path look like?

Comment: Your path seems to be hardcoded and not using the %userprofile% variable. Will try that next.